# When field is empty it outputs a blank line

Tags: php, custom-fields

I am using [Kirby](http://getkirby.com) for my CMS. I setup a custom field and when I have nothing inside it, it still outputs a blank line.

Backend screenshot showing no field value: http://cloud.chrisburton.me/LSyR 
View Source showing blank line (52): http://cloud.chrisburton.me/LSW0

**My Code:**

```
  <ul class="credits">
    <?php 
    if($page->client() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Client: </span>'.$page->client().'</li>';
    ?>

    <?php 
    if($page->art_direction() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Client: </span>'.$page->art_direcion().'</li>';
    ?>

    <?php 
    if($page->typeface() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$page->typeface().'</li>';
    ?>
  </ul>
```

How can I remove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WYSIWYG.

[image]

I'd suggest different approach...

```
<ul class="credits">
<?php
foreach(array('Client' => $page->client(), 'Direction' => $page->art_direction(), 'Typeface' => $page->typeface()) as $key => $value)
if($value != '') echo "\t<li><span>{$key}: </span>{$value}</li>\n";
?>
</ul>
```

Also, make sure you don't indent `<?php` and that it starts from position 0.

http://ideone.com/MBWLU0

Comment: @ChristopherBurton try my second suggestion. Also, you can add PHP_EOL in echo, and you could solve it like that.

Comment: Hmm. It's returning an error. I'm not that familiar with PHP, perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherBurton My bad with `empty`, try now, if that is not working, add `$this->{$method}() != ''` inside `if`.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton I've edited it, try now, it should work, also, is it `direcion` or `direction` ?

Comment: @ChristopherBurton You're pedantic :), try now. Make sure you don't have any spaces or tabs, like in your code... it must be exactly like this http://i.imgur.com/nwDFR.png ... do not indent it.

Comment: Haha, sorry. Now how would I add in those spans the way I have them in my initial post?

Comment: Damn you're good. Thanks for taking time out to help me on this. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="credits">
    <?php 
    if($page->client() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Client: </span>'.$page->client().'</li>';

    if($page->art_direction() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Client: </span>'.$page->art_direcion().'</li>';

    if($page->typeface() != '')
    echo '<li><span>Typeface: </span>'.$page->typeface().'</li>';

    ?>
  </ul>
```